# Reporting on multiple log files

Tags: sql, database, looker

We're using Looker for analytics and one connection streams in log files which are setup as new tables. They're basically all the same structure. The other connections show dimensions in a manner I'm used to within one file. How do I aggregate the daily files to pull data from?